# Media query not working in default android browser (okay in other browsers on same device)

Tags: android, css, media-queries, samsung-mobile

For some reason, the below is not working for Samsung Galaxy S3 devices in the default Android browser...

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 960px) {  
  /* Force 3 columns into 2 columns between 480px and 960px widths */
  .products-grid--max-3-col > li {
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .products-grid--max-3-col > li:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .products-grid--max-3-col > li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: none;
  }  
}
```

The reason for this to prevent the layout (product grid) flowing to 3 columns until the width is 961px upwards.

If you view the page in the Chrome browser on the same device, it shows 2 columns as expected but in the default Android browser, a rather messy 3 columns.

I'm absolutely stumped as to why this media query would not workj in the default Android browser. Should the above be sufficient in targeting the Galaxy S3's landscape view?

Answer (score 2):

Doh. Panic over, like a complete idiot, we had inserted a media query inside of another very long media query (didn't even realise).

This was not a problem for Chrome to throw a wobbly but clearly Android did not like this...

Anyway, moving the media query outside of the long media query resolved this for us. Thought about deleting the question but you never know, this might happen to someone else that happens to stumble across this...